# R Markdown version of \framesubtitle?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

The following is the least TeXy way I know of to create a beamer slide with a subtitle:

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
---

### Title of Slide
\framesubtitle{Subtitle of Slide}

Frame content.
```

Is there a way using no LaTeX, or does R Markdown not directly support slide subtitles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown doesn't support `\framesubtitle`s. It assumes you'll use the regular markdown `#`'s to denote sectional units, and a specific (highest) level is used for frame titles. Anything lower than that will only create headers *within* the frame, but not a subtitle. From the [Pandoc Manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#structuring-the-slide-show) (based on a specified `--slide-level` or the default):

> The document is carved up into slides according to the following rules:
>
> - A horizontal rule always starts a new slide.
> - A header at the slide level always starts a new slide.
> - Headers *below* the slide level in the hierarchy create headers *within* a slide.
> - Headers *above* the slide level in the hierarchy create "title slides," which just contain the section title and help to break the slide show into sections.
> - Content *above* the slide level will not appear in the slide show.

Of specific interest here is that "headers *below* the slide level in the hierarchy creates headers *within* a slide." These headers are actually `block` environments, since the following minimal markdown

```
---
title: A title
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    slide_level: 1
---

# Title of Slide
## Subtitle of Slide

Frame content.
```

creates a `.tex` file:

```latex
\title{A title}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Title of Slide}

\begin{block}{Subtitle of Slide}

Frame content.

\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your presentation is fairly simple, you can trick LaTeX into converting a `block` environment into the `\framesubtitle`. Add the following file (call it `block-to-framesubtitle.tex`) in your working folder:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{block}[1]{\framesubtitle{#1}\BODY}
```

Now you can use

```
---
title: A title
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 1
header-includes:
  - \input{block-to-framesubtitle}
---

# Title of Slide
## Subtitle of Slide

Frame content.
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, hack with `block-to-subtitle` doesn't works ;(

Comment: You are a hero. This works wonderfully. Personally, I did not make a different .tex file with the block-to-subtitle code in it, but put the code directly into the header-includes. This might also help @morsik.
Just add: 
header-includes:
- \usepackage{environ}
 - \RenewEnviron{block}[1]{\framesubtitle{#1}\BODY}
in your yaml header